# Quicksort ascending and descendding python

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to implement quicksort in place in ascending and descending order. The pivot element is the middle one. If the list is length 2 the pivot element is the first one. if the list length is even the pivot element is the last number of the first half of list. I have written a function which is called

```
quickSort(L, ascending True) L = List, true=ascending, false=descending

quickSort(testList1,False)



def quickSort(L, ascending = True):

  print('Quicksort, Parameter L:')
  print(L)


def quicksort(listToSort,lowIndex,highIndex):

  if ((highIndex - lowIndex) > 0): 
    p = partition(listToSort,lowIndex,highIndex)
    quicksort(listToSort,lowIndex,p-1)
    quicksort(listToSort,p+1,highIndex)

def partition(listToSort, lowIndex, highIndex): 
       divider = lowIndex
        pivot = highIndex

  for i in range(lowIndex,highIndex): 
    if (listToSort[i] < listToSort[pivot]): 
        listToSort[i], listToSort[divider] = listToSort[divider],listToSort[i]
        divider +=1
        listToSort[pivot], listToSort[divider] = listToSort[divider], listToSort[pivot]

        return divider

testList1 = [1,0,2,3,4,6,5,8,9,7]
testList2 = list([3.14159 , 1./127, 2.718 , 1.618 , -23., 3.14159])
testList3 = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

quicksort(testList1,0,9)
print (testList1)
quicksort(testList2,0,5)
print (testList2)
quicksort(testList3,0,9)
print (testList3)

quickSort(testList1,False)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind quick sort is partitioning a list into values that are less than a target value and the values greater than the target value. I used Haskell for the algorithm because algorithms can be directly expressed in Haskell. I then tried to translate it into Python. This turned into was more coding than I am accustomed to, to accomplish minor tasks.

In Haskell, it was necessary to import `partition` from `Data.List`
`partition` takes a list and produces 2 parts according to a supplied predicate. The predicate, in this case, is only `<=nv` because it is implied that each successive element of a list will be used as an argument. Haskell, like Python, can assign multiple values at a time.
The two parts of the `partition` output are bound to variables 'b' for beginning and 'e' for end because I am not very creative.
The word `where` is as in math.
`b` is concatenated with the insertion value which is then concatenated to 'e'
Haskell has functions that operate on functions. I give this function to `foldr` with required parameters. `foldr` uses the supplied function recursively with successive accumulated values.

The function is

```
ft nv ls = b++[nv]++e where (b,e) = partition (<=nv) ls
```

Executing it with `foldr` and it sorts the list. Place the `reverse` function in front of it for a reversed sorted list.

```
foldr ft [] [5,4,3,2,1,0,9,8,7,6]
```

**Edit 6-21-2018**\
I was trying to make the Python version recursive but failed. In Python, the iterative version came too easily. The two `filter` functions do the same thing as the `partition` function in Haskell.

```
def isort(ls):
    nls=ls
    for i in ls:
        nls= filter(lambda x: x<i,nls) +[i]+ filter(lambda x: x>i,nls)
    return(nls)
```